# How to read and parse XML response from SOAP request using curl in php?

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap

i'm sending a soap request using curl in php but the response is returning as string when i var_dump the response and i can't parse it to xml

```
$soapUrl = "https://hosting/Wsdl"; // asmx URL of WSDL

$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

                    <soapenv:Header/>
                       <soapenv:Body>
                        <MY DATA>
                       </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
    "Host: hosting,
    "Connection: Keep-Alive",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "SOAPAction: http://hosting.com/SOAPAction",
    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
);
$url = $soapUrl;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// converting
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// converting
var_dump($response);


$response1 = str_replace("<soap:Body>","",$response);
$response2 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$response1);

// convertingc to XML
$parser = simplexml_load_string($response);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($parser);
echo '</pre>';
```

the response returning as

```
 string(9965) "RESPONSE DATA"

object(SimpleXMLElement)#164 (0) { }
```

please any help and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

i use the following [XMLParser](https://www.php.net/xml_parse_into_struct)

```
<?

class XMLParser  {
    
    // raw xml
    private $rawXML;
    // xml parser
    private $parser = null;
    // array returned by the xml parser
    private $valueArray = array();
    private $keyArray = array();
    
    // arrays for dealing with duplicate keys
    private $duplicateKeys = array();
    
    // return data
    private $output = array();
    private $status;

    public function XMLParser($xml){
        $this->rawXML = $xml;
        $this->parser = xml_parser_create();
        return $this->parse();
    }

    private function parse(){
        
        $parser = $this->parser;
        
        xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0); // Dont mess with my cAsE sEtTings
        xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);     // Dont bother with empty info
        if(!xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $this->rawXML, $this->valueArray, $this->keyArray)){
            $this->status = 'error: '.xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($parser)).' at line '.xml_get_current_line_number($parser);
            return false;
        }
        xml_parser_free($parser);

        $this->findDuplicateKeys();

        // tmp array used for stacking
        $stack = array();         
        $increment = 0;
        
        foreach($this->valueArray as $val) {
            if($val['type'] == "open") {
                //if array key is duplicate then send in increment
                if(array_key_exists($val['tag'], $this->duplicateKeys)){
                    array_push($stack, $this->duplicateKeys[$val['tag']]);
                    $this->duplicateKeys[$val['tag']]++;
                }
                else{
                    // else send in tag
                    array_push($stack, $val['tag']);
                }
            } elseif($val['type'] == "close") {
                array_pop($stack);
                // reset the increment if they tag does not exists in the stack
                if(array_key_exists($val['tag'], $stack)){
                    $this->duplicateKeys[$val['tag']] = 0;
                }
            } elseif($val['type'] == "complete") {
                //if array key is duplicate then send in increment
                if(array_key_exists($val['tag'], $this->duplicateKeys)){
                    array_push($stack, $this->duplicateKeys[$val['tag']]);
                    $this->duplicateKeys[$val['tag']]++;
                }
                else{                
                    // else send in tag
                    array_push($stack,  $val['tag']);
                }
                $this->setArrayValue($this->output, $stack, $val['value']);
                array_pop($stack);
            }
            $increment++;
        }

        $this->status = 'success: xml was parsed';
        return true;

    }
    
    private function findDuplicateKeys(){
        
        for($i=0;$i < count($this->valueArray); $i++) {
            // duplicate keys are when two complete tags are side by side
            if($this->valueArray[$i]['type'] == "complete"){
                if( $i+1 < count($this->valueArray) ){
                    if($this->valueArray[$i+1]['tag'] == $this->valueArray[$i]['tag'] && $this->valueArray[$i+1]['type'] == "complete"){
                        $this->duplicateKeys[$this->valueArray[$i]['tag']] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            // also when a close tag is before an open tag and the tags are the same
            if($this->valueArray[$i]['type'] == "close"){
                if( $i+1 < count($this->valueArray) ){
                    if(    $this->valueArray[$i+1]['type'] == "open" && $this->valueArray[$i+1]['tag'] == $this->valueArray[$i]['tag'])
                        $this->duplicateKeys[$this->valueArray[$i]['tag']] = 0; 
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private function setArrayValue(&$array, $stack, $value){
        if ($stack) {
            $key = array_shift($stack);
            $this->setArrayValue($array[$key], $stack, $value);
            return $array;
        } else {
            $array = $value;
        }
    }
    
    public function getOutput(){
        return $this->output;
    }
    
    public function getStatus(){
        return $this->status;    
    }
       
}

?>

Usage:

$p = new XMLParser($xml);
$p->getOutput();
```

Comment: Hello but its not returning the tagnames. Can you let know how to get the tagnames